# Bulk stream support in WinUSB

Tags: usb, winusb

I'm using WinUSB to access the USB device and using bulk transfers for my application. When I provide stream number greater than 0 in the firmware and try bulk transfer from the desktop application, it is either giving error 31 or 433.
I wanted to understand is there any way to tell the host controller that stream should be used or any other configuration that I have to do before using WinUsb_WritePipe function for bulk transfer.

I'm using WinUsb_WritePipe function for the transfer. Not sure if I have to use any other functions or initializations to use streams from WinUsb. I'm calling WinUsb_WritePipe as shown below.
`WinUsb_WritePipe(handle, bulkOutPipe, writeBuffer, bulkOutTransferSize, &transferredLength, overlapped)`
here handle is WinUsb handle
bulkOutPipe is pipe ID
writeBuffer is the buffer containing data
bulkOutTransferSize is the size of the buffer
transferredLength is a pointer which gives the number of bytes transferred
overlapped is the object of structure LPOVERLAPPED

Comment: Please show your code. Then we might understand what you mean by "stream" – a term that I cannot find in the WinUSB documentation.

Comment: Stream is added in USB superspeed. It is the bmAttributes field present in the SuperSpeed endpoint companion descriptor. For bulk transfer bmAttributes value can be in the range of 0-16.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, WinUSB does not support SuperSpeed streams. There are several other things it doesn't support either (e.g. select a specific configuration). I think this blog post from 2012 still holds: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-usb-blog/using-winusb-for-usb-3-0-superspeed-devices-on-windows-8/ba-p/270761. *"WinUSB does not support communication with individual streams of a SuperSpeed bulk endpoint."*

Comment: Thanks @Codo.
Do you suggest any alternatives to WinUSB which I can use for SuperSpeed streams?

Comment: You probably need to write a WDM driver. That's both inconvenient for you (far more complex) and your users (they need to install a driver to use your hardware).

Comment: Okay. Thanks @Codo